# find bijection $f :\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\} \to \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0),(1,0),(-1,0)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

find a bijection

$$f :\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\} \to \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0),(1,0),(-1,0)\}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Start with the identity function on $\Bbb R^2$. Alter it (where necessary) to a bijection taking points you'll be removing from the domain to points you'll be removing from the codomain (and vice versa, for simplicity). Restrict domain and codomain appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be a piecewise function, but shouldn't be too difficult. Let $$f:\left[\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\} \right] \longrightarrow \left[ \mathbb{R}-\{(0,0),(1,0),(-1,0)\} \right]$$ be defined by

$f((x,y)) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       (x,y)\ \ \ \ \ \ if\ (x,y) \neq (1,0) \ or\ (-1,0)\\
       (0,1)\ \ \ \ \ \ if\ (x,y)=(1,0)\\
       (1,1)\ \ \ \ \ \ if\ (x,y)=(-1,0)
     \end{array}
   \right.$

By construction $f$ is injective. It is also easy to show $f$ is onto, so $f$ is a bijection.